# On Parse security

Tags: parse-platform, acl, parse-server

Maybe someone can help me to better understand Parse's ACL mechanism by confirming/refuting the following scenario:

- User A creates an object and grants read/write permissions to users A and B.
- User B can fetch the object, remove A from the ACL, and save it.
- As a result, A -- the creator of the object -- no longer can change or even find the object.

If this is correct, I consider it a security issue. Is there a way to prevent client-side changes to the ACL of an object so I can manage the ACL entirely in Cloud Code?

**EDIT:** As pointed out by Mazel Tov, one way of dealing with this issue is to prohibit any direct client access and instead only use Cloud Code (with master key overriding) to access the data. I don't consider that a viable solution because this approach gives up most of Parse's benefits. ACLs are a great means of controlling access rights, but -- at least in some usage contexts -- giving clients the power of overriding these settings seems dangerous.

So for me the question remains: if Parse's ACLs theoretically allow any user with Write access for an object to manipulate the access rights of all other users, does nobody else see this as a security problem?

Comment: yes you can do it entirely in cloud code, that is why we have Master Key :-)... when using it it will override any permission...

Comment: Thanks for that hint! I updated the post accordingly.

Comment: There is also a Security feature on all classes, you can view it from the dashboard on the right side...you can set Roles in Parse .... You can always check if the author of the object is in the ACL in some afterSave trigger... I dont see any security threat here, only opportunities and great framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others in a similar situation: I did not find a solution to this problem (at least to me it is a problem, not an "opportunity"), so I ended up using ACLs for controlling read access only (all write access is private), and running my own server-side permission system with *lots* of Cloud Code functions for all kinds of write access.